# Problems with Binding Checkboxes in a Listview in xaml Code

Tags: c#, xaml

What i have:

i have a ListView with 6 Values(string) and a Name(string). I also added a Checkbox for each row.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pES9.jpg)

Struct:

```
public struct ststuff
{
    public bool bEnable { get; set; }
    public string sone  { get; set; }
    public string stwo  { get; set; }
    public string stree { get; set; }
    public string sa { get; set; }
    public string sb { get; set; }
    public string sc { get; set; }
    public string sName { get; set; }
}
```

Collection:

```
private ObservableCollection<ststuff> _astuff;
```

Some Code:

```
    <ListView Margin="10,100,10,10" Name="lvstuff" ItemsSource="{Binding astuff,Mode=TwoWay,ElementName=window}" SelectedIndex="{Binding nIndex,Mode=TwoWay,ElementName=window}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="[]">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding bEnable,ElementName=window}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="a" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sa}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="b" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sb}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="c" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sc}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="1" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sone}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="2" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding stwo}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="3" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding stree}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Now what i want:

Click on one check box and save true/false in a a value.(e.g. _astuff[0].bEnable for first checkbox)

Atm. if i click on one box all boxes goes check/uncheck because i binded all to the same value.

Somehow i want to bind IsChecked Property of Checkbox to bEnable of my struct but i dont know how!

Answer (score 0):

I got it maybe not the best way but it works.

```
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cb = e.OriginalSource as CheckBox;

        int index = _astuff.IndexOf((ststuff)(cb).DataContext);

        ststuff stuff= _astuff[index];

        stuff.bEnable = true;

        _astuff[index] = stuff;
    }
```

The problem is that the selected index of ListView dont change by check/uncheck a checkbox. In this way you can find the index in your collection. You have to do the same with Uncheck event.